# Компиляция сервлетов

Tags: java, java-ee, сервлеты

Вообщем пытаюсь скомпилировать сервлет:

```
javac -classpath "/var/lib/tomcat6/common/lib/servlet-api.jar:classes" sel.java
```

Вылетает:

```
    sel.java:2: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.*;
^
sel.java:3: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.*;
^
sel.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
public class sel extends HttpServlet {
                         ^
  symbol: class HttpServlet
sel.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
                   ^
  symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
  location: class sel
sel.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
                                               ^
  symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
  location: class sel
sel.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
                                                                                                 ^
  symbol:   class ServletException
  location: class sel
6 errors
```

Насколько я понимаю всё это из-за того, что в "/var/lib/tomcat6/common/" lib-а просто нет. Ну и servlet-api.jar соответственно нет тоже.

**Вопрос:** что делать?

*p.s. код не показываю  потому, что похоже он вообще ни в чём не виноват, и ошибка не в нём*

Comment: Походу этот servlet-api.jar скачивать надо... Хотя некоторые пишут, что у них он лежит в этом libs. Вообщем, те, у кого tomcat6, поделитесь этой штукой плиз

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Качай первый zip в Пункте Core http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi
И там в папке lib лежит твой servlet-api.jar

Comment: Ссылка на архив, решил облегчить тебе жизнь http://apache.cp.if.ua/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.37/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.37.zip

Answer (score 4):

servlet-api.jar не входит в поставку JavaSE, соответственно да, данная библиотека должна быть доступна в classpath при компиляции проекта.

Вы можете скачать этот jar-файл или воспользоваться инструментами, решающими задачу управления зависимостями (например, Maven, Ivy).

В любом случае не стоит расчитывать на наличие библиотеки где-то в файловой системе вашего окружения. В худшем случае положите нужные библиотеки в директорию `lib` вашего проекта.

Comment: Тем ни менее пишут, что это servlet-api.jar должен где-то быть в томкате. Ладно, тогда где его скачать?

Comment: @danpetuk Да, должен быть. Но как правило, продуктовое и девелоперское окружение - это разные вещи. Соответственно в девелоперском окружении данная библиотека нужна в compile time, а в продуктовом (тестовом) - в runtime. Потому правильно в покте не завязываться на tomcat.